# How to cancel out $\sin^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm currently trying to solve $\cos^4x-\sin^4x=\frac12$. My first step was to simplify this into $\left(\cos^2x-\sin^2x\right)^2=\frac12$. Using the trig identity $\cos^2x = 1 - \sin^2x$ I rearranged this into $\left(1-2\sin^2x\right)^2 = \frac 1 2$. This finally became $\sin^2x = \frac{\sqrt{\frac12}-1}{-2}$. Is there a way to solve for $x$ from here? I don't know if it's possible t0 take $\sin^{-2}$ of both sides. When I put this into wolfram alpha, it yields $\pi\left(n-\frac16\right)$ and $\pi\left(n+\frac16\right)$, but I'm not sure how they are getting this.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your question. It is very difficult to comprehend in its current form. Also, $\cos^4x - \sin^4x\neq\left(\cos^2x - \sin^2x\right)^2$.

Comment: No!  $\cos^4x-\sin^4x\neq(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2$, but $\cos^4x-\sin^4x=(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$.

Comment: @user10354138 I think you mean $\cos^4x - \sin^4x$ on the RHS?

Comment: @an4s no, I mean $\cos^2x-\sin^2x$, because $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$.

Comment: @user10354138 it makes sense now that you have edited your comment. At first, it looked like you meant to say $(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2$.

Comment: Thank you @user10354138 ! That was a huge oversight on my part. Since cos^2+sin^2 becomes 1, I can ignore that. For cos^2x-sin^2x, should I convert that into cos2x or 1-2sin^2x?

Comment: @SpicyDiablo it doesn't matter. You should get the same result either way.

Comment: $\cos 2x$ is quicker, but you could use $2\cos^2x-1$ or $1-2\sin^2x$ if you really want to (two cases $\pm\dots$ to consider instead of just one in $\cos 2x$).

Comment: @user10354138 I used cos2x and got the same answer. However, If I used cos^2x how would I get rid of the cos^2?

Comment: @SpicyDiablo First take the square root, then the inverse cosine. $\cos^2$ means : take the cosine, then square that : so to invert it, you first undo the square (by square rooting) then undo the cosine (by inverse cosine).

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон I see. Thank you. Doing that I got pi/4. Apparently there are multiple solutions though. Should just that one be fine or is there a way to find and express the general solution?

Comment: The "inverse cosine" doesn't have one solution : so for example the inverse sine of $\frac 12$ is not just $\frac {\pi} 6$ , but there are more solutions , right (like $\frac{5\pi}{6}$)? So I think while taking the inverse cosine you get the general solution as well, provided you extend to taking the other solutions.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Ah okay. I was thinking it would be npi/4 based on what I got but apparently it is pi(n+(1/6)). Do you know how they obtained that from pi/4? Thanks so much.

Comment: @SpicyDiablo I need to go into the problem more to see how that comes and if you've made any error along the way. Oh, +1, I like the fact you conversed with users. I think you should edit some of the things they said into the body of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to factor out by using  trig identity squares sum = 1 at first ( otherwise you go too far and cannot come back). Next the squares difference as $\cos 2 \theta=\dfrac12$

$$ 2 \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{ 3}\pm 2n \pi\quad i.e., \theta= \pm \pi(n+\frac{1}{6})$$